# How can I implement custom user authentication using Azure Function (HTTP Trigger)

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, serverless

I want to use Azure Function [HTTP Trigger] as Web API backend for my Angular 4 application. I have an Azure Database which has a table 'Users', I want to use that user table and implement something like OAuth token and with the help of that token I want to access other functions. I have used [Authorize] annotation just like it used in Web API but it didn't work.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank You,